# Tortoise SVN merging issues

Tags: merge, tortoisesvn

i'm trying to merge two projects, but no success.

once i started some project, and my partner took a copy of it.
since then i've worked with ui (continued with the project i started) and my partner worked with db (he has added some classes and edited couple of already created classes).

now we are trying to merge these two projects, but we cant. we always getting some error messages...

any help how to do that will be grate (all the merging tutorial i've found didnt help much)

Comment: Hint: any time you're getting error messages, post them :-)

Comment: Depends a lot on the error messages.  If they're conflicts, you'll just have to resolve them.

Comment: If you can provide the error message, that would be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure what the error is.  But if all else fails, you can manually merge your two projects using kdiff3 or WinMerge, then check in this merged project.

Comment: Thanks, 
It didnt resolved the "tree conflict problem" but i did merge it eventually, and now i can upload the merged project...